# Не многовато ли питонов?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Понятно, что нужны разные метки для второго и третьего питонов, но действительно ли нужно столько меток для подверсий третьего?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: предлагаешь сжечь питона? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, смёрджить)))

Comment: попробуйте описание метки python прочитать

Comment: @jfs, что неужто подверсии так сильно отличаются?

Comment: Если у автора проблема специфична для конкретной версии Питона, то не важно сильно или не сильно отличаются (что бы это не значило). К примеру такие метки полезны, если автор использует какую-нибудь старую версию где отсутствует  функциональность доступная в новых версиях, [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/q/296499/4279).

Comment: @jfs, ну вот в моем уютном мире джаваскриптика есть интернет эксплореры, которых минимум четыре сильно отличающихся версии сейчас со своим специфическим набором багов. Но те 10-15 вопросов  для которых проблема чисто для ie9 и больше нигде, спокойно живут в рамках общей метки

Comment: @jfs я не настаиваю что так и должно быть, кмк оба варианта имеют право на жизнь

Comment: @jfs, это [meta-tag:обсуждение], так что предлагаю идти в ответы ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy: *"Убедитесь, что предоставляете полное описание ситуации, достаточное для аргументированного обсуждения."* (без упоминания рекомендации использования в python метке, нельзя рассматривать ваш вопрос "полным описанием ситуации"). Вы тратите время.

Comment: Kill it with fire!

Comment: @jfs, описание метки тоже можно менять. По-прежнему предлагаю написать об этом в ответе.

Comment: О проблеме в специфичной версии питона всегда можно написать, например, в заголовке, а в этих метках я никакой пользы не вижу, особенно учитывая, что с близкой к единице вероятностью проблемы могут воспроизводиться и на других (например, более старых) версиях.

Comment: C @andreymal не согласен. От версии к версии "возможности" ПО меняются. Простой пример - если участник начнет обсуждать Qt 2.* - лично я тему даже и не гляну (ибо компетентен >= строго 5.*). И тем не менее, если он "обозначится" меткой "Qt" - он заберет мое время жизни. Впустую, и не по фэншую.

Comment: @Majestio речь не про qt-2.x и qt-5.x, а qt-5.1, qt-5.2, qt-5.3, qt-5.4, qt-5.5, qt-5.6, qt-5.7 и так далее. Вы точно уверены, что все эти метки действительно нужны? :)

Comment: Совсем не уверен ... но есть некоторые мысли а-ля " а если" ... А если ввести некоторое (пусть и большое) количество меток-версий? Типа [1.*]..[99.*],  [\*.1]..[\*.99], [\*.*.1]..[\*.*.99] - итог = +300 меток, но можем скомбинировать любую версию. Только под вопросом, а если надо, типа ">10.1.11"... Понимаю, тема ну оч сырая, ну а если?)

Comment: Касаемо любых меток. Нужно разумное разделение. Чем больше разновидностей одной метки, тем хуже. Основное назвначение метки - ускорять поиск ответа. Но как теме присваивать метки, если вопрос подходит под все 8-15 штук? Метить тему всеми? А если не всеми - автор ограничивает шансы страждущих.

Answer (score 10):

Система с Python метками, как я понимаю, была сделана по образу и подобию основного сайта.

Раньше я поддерживал эту систему, но посмотрев ещё раз на использование этих меток участниками я начал думать, что для нашего сообщества этого может быть слишком много.

Пользователи не всегда даже указывают основную метку вопроса [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), используя только метку основной версии [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) или [python-2.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x). Некоторые пользователи указывают сразу несколько взаимоисключающих (по замыслу) меток за раз.

Также многие задающие вопросы обычно указывают информацию о точной версии в самом вопросе и для наших объёмов этого может быть достаточно.

Так что я считаю, что уменьшение количества версионных меток Python не помешает пользователям получать качественные ответы, при желании для нужной им версии, и можно оставить только три основных метки.