# Как использовать и интерпретировать версионные метки?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Много думал про метку html5 ([здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4597/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bc-html5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba-html-css3-%d0%ba-css?noredirect=1#comment23948_4597) можно почитать моё недовольство её существованием), но в итоге надумал более общий вопрос.

Я так понимаю, текущая практика использования версионных меток [примерно такая](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3826/): если версия не указана, то работаем с последней имеющейся, а если указана, то только с указанной.

Реальность такова, что авторы вопросов тупо пихают последнюю имеющуюся версию в метки, не особо задумываясь о её надобности: html5, [python-3.6](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4279/) и так далее. Причём в большинстве случаев вопрос охватывает не только последнюю версию, но и многие предыдущие. Например, львиная доля вопросов с меткой html5 и ответов на них прекрасно вписываются и в html4.

Ну, допустим, вопрос действительно про какую-то новую фичу последней версии (canvas, asyncio и т.п.). А что будет, когда выйдет новая версия? В html6 вряд ли уберут canvas. asyncio появился в Python 3.4 (а ещё есть бэкпорт для 3.3), в 3.5 появился async/await, и в 3.6 ничего из этого не пропало. Все вопросы и ответы, написанные под старую версию, с большой вероятностью будут актуальны и для новых версий. Но метки у вопросов с конкретной старой версией ведь останутся!

После выхода новой версии можно было бы написать новый ответ (или дополнить старый). Например, после выхода Python 3.5 можно было бы в старом вопросе написать новый ответ с чем-нибудь вроде «В Python 3.5 добавили await, и теперь такой-то костыль стал не нужен, теперь можно сделать проще так-то и так-то» и тем самым улучшить базу знаний. Однако бездумно проставленная версионная метка python-3.4 не даст это сделать, если её интерпретировать как «если версия указана, то работаем только с указанной».

Может, я неправильно интерпретирую метки? Может, не стоит использовать метки для последних версий и стоит удалить метку python-3.6 и заменить её на просто python до тех пор, пока не выйдет 3.7? Или может версионные метки вообще не нужны и стоит ограничиться упоминанием версии в текстах вопросов и ответов? Или всё же стоит тупо создать дубликат вопроса, но без версионной метки, и написать там ответ про await?

В общем, как это всё дело правильно использовать, и как писать новые ответы на старые вопросы, касающиеся новых версий?

Comment: придерживаюсь простого правила: если не уверен, что твой вопрос имеет чёткую специфику - поставь общую метку без номера. А когда знаешь, что вопрос специфичен для конкретной версии - поставь и общую и частную.

Comment: @AK я тоже примерно так же делаю, но вот в чужих вопросах метки особо не поредактируешь, могут и по рукам дать

Comment: По моему все просто: автор вопроса ставит метку той версии, для которой ему требуется решение, если ему без разницы - ставит метку без версии. Тот факт, что существует решение средствами более старой версии, чем хочет автор, ничего не меняет.

Comment: @VadimTagil после выхода какого-нибудь питона 3.7 автор начнёт применять ответ, написанный для 3.6, и для 3.7 тоже, но возвращаться в вопрос и убирать версионную метку он вряд ли будет :(